# pycassa remove specific key from super column

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

I know how to remove an entire super column, but not an individual key within. My google kung fu has failed me.

so, to remove a super column:

```
cf_accounts.remove('key', ['super_column'])
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Help appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but since you're asking, it sounds like your application doesn't already depend on supercolumns. If possible, stop using them now before your dependence grows; they are long-deprecated and are otherwise problematic.

Comment: @thepaul thanks for the tip. What have functionality has replaced super columns?

Comment: Composites have replaced them, although even before composites were officially supported, it was a better idea to pack multiple values into one by yourself rather than use supercolumns. For information on how to use composites with CQL 3, read closely the examples at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 .

Comment: thanks. I will use composites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `super_column` parameter.

```
cf.remove('key', super_column='super_column', columns=['sub_column'])
```

With that said, @the paul's advice is definitely sound.

Comment: what about if I want to delete all row_keys and columns? keys were generated dynamically i.e. ´row_key0, row_key1...row_keyn´

Comment: I suggest using truncate() for that.  Otherwise, you'll need to delete them all individually or make a Batch (see pycassa.batch) with all of the individual deletions.